# Android Studio with two monitors

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 0.8.2
I am not able to get it working with two monitors.
If I have the main application in the left monitor, I want to be able to have the other windows like Event Log,Messages, etc.. docked together in the right monitor.

I can get the windows over to the right, but only if I check floating on the window. And when I do get the window over there to the right, when I click anywhere back on the left monitor, the windows in the right monitor disappear.
I am also not able to figure out how to dock multiple windows together in the right monitor.

I was able to do all of this very easily with Eclipse. 
Should I just go back to Eclipse?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the [official documentation for Tool Windows](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea-tool-windows.html).

In particular, you may want to refer to the [Viewing Modes](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-modes.html)'s **Fixed / floating mode** section on how to disable transparency for floating windows. Tool windows should not disappear when they lose focus, but they can become semi-transparent.

Additionally, you can have a read through [this article](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/) which provides a lot of useful information for Eclipse users when switching to IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio.

Answer (score 8):

If you intent to have dual monitors run android studio.

1. Open the main screen of AS in your primary monitor.
2. Select the bar which you want to drag to secondary monitor.
3. Hit Right click and you should get the following options: **Floating Mode**, **Docked Mode** **etc..**
4. Select ***Windowed Mode*** & you should have a your desired in windows mode
5. Drag the window to secondary monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Drag the debug window to another monitor, maximize and select `Pinned` from the settings (gear button top right).

So `Pinned mode` and `Floating mode` should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

With 3.5.0

Just drag the editor tab to the new monitor.
It should turn into a window.

Then you have the main window that holds the docked tool window(s) and a separate editor window.

Comment: I did this but dragged the editing window to my main monitor. Dragging every single item from the bottom bar (debug, logcat, terminal, etc) as most suggestions ask here is a PITA. I'd personally prefer an option to drag the whole bottom bar to a new window since those are the support functions I use all of the time, but don't need to be on the main screen.

Comment: @Brettins You should be able to drag individual items or tabs into the initial window, next to existing tabs, and then somehow save the "view" configuration

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.4.2

Click **Window/Active Tool Window/Floating Mode**

Now you can drag windows to the second monitor.